# Matplotlib Plot confusion

Tags: python, matplotlib, group-by

I'm not sure what is going on here but I have two seemingly similar bits of code designed to produce graphs in the same format:

```
apple_fcount = apple_f1.groupby("Year")["Domain Category"].nunique("count")
plt.figure(1); apple_fcount.plot(figsize=(12,6))
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Number of Fungicides used')
plt.title('Number of fungicides used on apples in the US')
plt.savefig('C:/Users/User/Documents/Work/Year 3/Project/Plots/Apple/apple fcount')
```

This one produces the graph how I would like it to be seen; y axis shows number of fungicides, x axis shows the respective years. However, the following code, on a different dataset prints a usable graph but the x axis shows years as '1, 2, 3, ...' instead of the actual years.

```
apple_yplot = apple_y1.groupby('Year')['Value'].sum()
plt.figure(3); apple_yplot.plot(figsize=(12,6))
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Yield / lb per acre')
plt.title('Graph of apple yield in the US over time')
plt.savefig('C:/Users/User/Documents/Work/Year 3/Project/Plots/Apple/Yield.png')
```

The only discernable difference I see in the code is that the first counts .nunique() datapoints, whilst the second is a .sum() of all data in the year. I can't imagine thats the reason behind this issue though. Both .groupby() lines print in the same format, with year being correctly displayed there.

apple_fcount:

```
Year
1991    19
1993    19
1995    21
1997    26
1999    28
2001    27
2003    31
2005    37
2007    30
2009    35
2011    32
Name: Domain Category, dtype: int64
```

apple_yplot:

```
Year
2007    405399
2008    541180
2009    483130
2010    473150
2011    468120
2012    417710
2013    529470
2014    510700
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: can you show us what the contents of `apple_fcount` and `apple_yplot` are?

Comment: edited to add the outputs of them, for reference. I can't see the issue, honestly' I thought the code would print identical graph formats.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The years at the x axis of the y_plot graph are labelled 1,2,3,..., when they should be labelled with the actual year 2007,2008,2009,....

This is the case for the fcount graph, but I can't find out where in the code that change is happening. From my perspective they should both be in the second format